# Vue.js + Element UI - How to change value el-switch

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, parseint, element-ui

I have data from server. The response data is integer 1 or 0, In view i use element ui el-switch, it set value with boolean true or false.

Is there anyway can help me?
It's my code

```
<div class="row">
          <el-col :span="9">
            <el-form-item>
              <p style="margin-top: 15px">sale in POS</p>
            </el-form-item>
          </el-col>
          <el-col :span="15" class="switch-varian">
            <el-switch inactive-color="#ff4949" v-model="product.pos_hidden" @change="valuePOS"></el-switch>
            <div v-if="product.pos_hidden === 1">
              <p class="desc-switch">
                <strong>Yes</strong>
              </p>
              <p class="desc-switch">This Product Sale in POS</p>
            </div>
            <div v-else>
              <p class="desc-switch">
                <strong>No</strong>
              </p>
              <p>This Product Not Sale in POS</p>
            </div>
          </el-col>
        </div>

methods: {
loadData() {
  this.loading = true
  let headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + window.accessToken
  }

  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: BASE_API + 'product/' + this.$route.params.id,
    params: this.params,
    headers: headers
  })
    .then(response => {
      this.product = response.data.data
      this.loading = false
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      this.loading = true
      this.$notify({
        title: 'Error: ' + error,
        type: 'warning',
        message: 'Error: ' + error
      })
    })
},
valuePOS(val) {
  if (val === true) {
    fooBar | 1
  } else {
    fooBar | 0
  }
}
```

**Expected :** 
I want to change value from response to boolean value.
And then i'll edit that value and send request to server with new value as an integer value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `active-value` and `inactive-value`. [Document](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/switch#switch)

```
  <el-switch
    v-model="product.pos_hidden"
    :active-value="1"
    :inactive-value="0">
  </el-switch>
```

Comment: i have try
but the value is string not an integer

it''s response from server (pos_hidden:0)
and it''s from value change (pos_hidden:"1")

Comment: I've updated, you can bind value to make it becomes integer